# In how many ways can they be arranged such that any two green marbles won't be adjacent?

Tags: permutations

> There are $2$ blue, $4$ yellow and $3$ green identical marbles. In how many ways can they be arranged such that any two green marbles won't be adjacent?

_B_B_Y_Y_Y_Y_

Let us evaluate in how many ways blue and yellow marbles can be arranged. Since the marbles are identical, we have that $$P = \dfrac{6!}{4!\cdot 2!}$$

There are also $7$ slots which we can fill in green marbles, $7$ slots out of $3$

$$7\times 6\times 5$$

Hence, we get

$$7\times 6\times 5 \times \dfrac{6!}{4!\cdot 2!}$$

Am I right?

Regards

Comment: Can anyone comment on it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select three slots out of seven you need to divide by $3!$ because the green marbles are identical.  The number of ways to select them is $7 \choose 3$